# Finite measure in a metric space with Borel $\sigma$-field is a regular measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$\newcommand{\scrF}{\mathcal{F}}$
$\newcommand{\scrO}{\mathcal{O}}$
**Proposition:** Let $\Omega$ be a metric space and $\scrF = \sigma(\scrO)$ i.e the Borel $\sigma$-field on $\Omega$. Let $\mu$ be a measure defined on $(\Omega, \scrF)$ and suppose that $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$, then $\mu$ is a regular measure.

To do the proof we first let $\scrF'$ be the set of all $E \in \scrF$ such that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find a closed set $F$ and open set $O$ satisfying $F \subseteq E \subseteq O$ and $\mu(O \setminus F) < \varepsilon$. We want to show that $\scrF' = \scrF$ and we start by showing it's a $\sigma$-field. Showing it contains the empty-set and is closed under complements is straightforward, but the reference I have uses a more complicated argument to prove closure under countable unions which doesn't make sense to me, in particular because the argument below seems right to me. Is there an issue in the argument I have written below?

> Suppose that $(E_n)$ is a sequence in $\scrF'$. Then for all $n \geq 1$ there exist $F_n$ closed and $O_n$ open such that $F_n \subseteq E_n \subseteq O_n$ and $\mu(O_n \setminus F_n) < \varepsilon/n$. Note that because $F_n \subseteq E_n$ we have that $F=\cap_{n=1}^\infty F_n \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ and moreover $F$ is closed as the intersection of closed sets is closed. Also $\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^\infty O_n =O$ and also $O$ is open as the union of open sets. Then consider
> \begin{align*}
> \mu(O \setminus F) & = \mu\left( \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty O_n \right) \cap \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty F_n \right)^c \right)\newline
> & =  \mu\left( \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty O_n \right) \cap \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n^c \right) \right)\newline
> &=\mu \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (O_n \cap F_n^c) \right)\newline
> & = \mu \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (O_n\setminus F_n)\right)\newline
> & \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(O_n \setminus F_n)\newline
> & < n \frac{\varepsilon}{n} \newline
> & < \varepsilon.
> \end{align*}

Where here passing to the summation follows by sub-additivity of a measure. Rather than do this the notes I have define a sequence of sets by
$$
A_n = \left( \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty O_j \right) \setminus \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty F_k \right), \; n \geq 1,
$$
and then applies continuity from below to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(A_n) < \varepsilon$.

So I guess where is the mistake in my argument, because it seems like it would have been taken if it was valid. Thanks in advance for the clarification.

Comment: There are two problems: First, the step from the second to the third line does not work. Second, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon/n=\infty$, tough that can be fixed by replacing $\epsilon/n$ with $\epsilon/2^n$.

Comment: To make the problem very explicit: Let $F_1\subseteq E_1\subseteq O_1$ and $F_2\subseteq E_2\subseteq O_2$ and with $O_1$ and $O_2$ disjoint. Then $F_1$ and $F_2$ are disjoint too and $\mu(O\setminus F)=\mu(O)$. Also, $\mu((O_1\cup O_2)\cap(F_1^C\cup F_2^C) )\neq \mu((O_1\cap F_1^C)\cup(O_2\cap F_2^C))$.

Comment: Ah sorry yeah the sum is straightforward. I don't think my basic set theory is sharp enough having made the first mistake. Thanks @MichaelGreinecker. If you paste either response in an answer I'll accept it for the purpose of clearing it from unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step from the second to the third line is not valid: Let $F_1\subseteq E_1\subseteq O_1$ and $F_2\subseteq E_2\subseteq O_2$ and with $O_1$ and $O_2$ disjoint. Then $F_1$ and $F_2$ are disjoint too and $\mu(O\setminus F)=\mu(O)$. Also, $$\mu((O_1\cup O_2)\cap(F_1^C\cup F_2^C) )\neq \mu((O_1\cap F_1^C)\cup(O_2\cap F_2^C)).$$

Also, there is an issue in how you sum the remainders; you get multiple of the divergent [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)).